# How to insert a value starting with 0 in NVARCHAR column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, I am trying to insert a 6 digit string value into a `NVARCHAR` column. But it stores the data perfectly until the 6 digit string starts with **0**.

```
Ex: 001212 -->stores as 1212
    121212 -->stores as 121212
    012121 -->stores as 12121
    120121 -->stores as 120121
```

I searched for the solution on stackoverflow but I can get solution for this .

But I have an idea that validate the string length if it is not 6 digit then adding **0** .

if it is correct can someone help me to do it .

Comment: Specify as string literal instead of integer value, e.g `'001212'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically what you want to do is right pad the number.  SQL Server doesn't have a built in function, but it is not to hard to write an expression to do it:

```
select right(replicate('0', 6) + convert(varchar(255), @num), 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

If it's a string work with it like it's a string. That is, enclose literal values in single quotes (and add the `N`prefix for `nvarchar`s).

```
INSERT INTO elbat (nmuloc)
VALUES (N'000007');
```